# Repairing earth link to conduit

Tags: electrical, conduit

The wiring in my property uses the conduit as the earth. I've checked the earth resistance and have no problems there. Unfortunately some of the ceiling lights are not properly grounded as the tabs on the end of the fixing box have been snapped off at some point in the past. Without making a mess of the ceiling there is no way to replace the fixing box. This means there is no obvious way to join the light fitting ground to the conduit. Are there any tips on how to do this? I don't think soldering a wire onto the conduit pipe will work.
Thanks.

Comment: I do a ton of EMT but am not following what a "fixing box" is. Can you shoot us a picture of what you're talking about?

Comment: To be honest I'm making an assumption about the fixing box. Looking up at the light hole all you see something similar to the attached but with the tabs snapped off and the depth is much greater before the wires make the right angle turn. https://www.screwfix.com/p/deta-galvanised-metal-conduit-terminal-box-25mm/1476J?tc=JT9&ds_kid=92700019905977215&ds_rl=1248181&ds_rl=1245250&ds_rl=1249481&gclid=CjwKCAjw1tDaBRAMEiwA0rYbSKTlLnMa_0n-DkepZ6kIJKCVEmvQmVDB7H0YgTwdjgf0K-dSov8kSBoCLCcQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds&dclid=CIK0pomfs9wCFfAN0wodxt8Odg

Comment: Where are you on this planet @Reuben?

Comment: In the united kingdom.